# Why can't I run CassandraDB on Windows 10 with the latest Java installed?

Tags: cassandra

When I try to start up Cassandra DB under windows 10, It complains about the Java version:

```
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

I believe I have the latest Java installed:

```
java --version
java 13.0.2 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I've installed Apache Cassandra 3.11.9 (the open source version not the Datastax version).

Why doesn't Cassandra recognize this version of Java? Do I need to install a different version of Java to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to install Java 8 to run Cassandra 3.11 - it will not work with Java 13 (yes, I understand that error message isn't clear).  Support for Java > 8 was [added only to Cassandra 4.0](https://cassandra.apache.org/blog/2020/07/20/apache-cassandra-4-0-beta1.html), that is currently in beta.
Also, on Windows it would be easier to use Docker to run Cassandra - there are different difficulties with running Cassandra on Windows.

Comment: Ok thank you. Yes I agree running Docker would be a better solution. I would like to keep Java 13 for my development efforts. Thanks for letting me know!